# Another SonarQube analysis is already in progress for this project

Tags: amazon-web-services, sonarqube

I have a monorepo, using sonar-scanner, in every PR that someone opens, sonar is activate on my CI (aws codebuild), but always returning this message: "Another SonarQube analysis is already in progress for this project"

there is a way to clean the path where the logs are?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOj7U.png)

Comment: Check for any pending **Background Tasks** in Sonarqube. If it exists, remove it and then retry your scan. Please check here for more details https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/background-tasks/

Comment: Please add error messages as code to your question and not as pictures. It makes it easier for others to find you question and do understand it without having to follow links to external resources

Answer (score 0):

I was running with de --parallel flag on my CI and hadn't noticed